# Android - get touch event dispatched correctly after relocating view

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to use [virtual-joystick-android](https://github.com/controlwear/virtual-joystick-android/) for my project, but I faced an issue I cannot currently resolve it.

I need to change position of the joystick every time user touches screen, in other words joystick has to be relocated some-when during touch dispatching flow. The problem is that after relocation I have to touch for the screen second time to be able to manipulate joystick. Layout I use looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/joystickLayout">

    <io.github.controlwear.virtual.joystick.android.JoystickView
        android:id="@+id/joystick"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        custom:JV_buttonSizeRatio="25%"
        custom:JV_fixedCenter="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I try just to change its position inside RelativeLayout like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(joystick.getLayoutParams());
params.setMargins((int) motionEvent.getX() - joystick.getWidth() / 2, (int) motionEvent.getY() - joystick.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0);
joystick.setLayoutParams(params);
```

inside RelativeLayout's onTouch, event is dispatched to the children before being dispatched to the parent, and dispatching them manually doesn't seem to provide children with future events (move, up). If I try to relocate JoystickView inside overridden dispatchTouchEvent, event dispatching system seem to use old bounds for further touch dispatching.

Any thoughts?